# Route 53 Domain will not point to AWS Lightsail instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I am attempting to set up a new website in AWS Lightsail and am unable to get my domain to point to my Lightsail instance. The domain was purchased in Route 53, and in that domain's hosted zone I have set up an A record to point to my instance's static IP. When I navigate to that static IP directly, I can access the site without issue.

These issues began occurring after attempting to create an SSL certificate in the Lightsail distribution tools. After configuring the distribution and DNS Zone, I edited the name servers in both the domain registry as well as the hosted zone in Route 53 to match what is recommended by AWS under the Lightsail DNS Zone information. It has been over two days since these name servers were changed, and I still cannot navigate to my instance through this domain.

Any suggestions even for how to troubleshoot this issue would be very much appreciated. Has anyone run into similar issues with Lightsail and Route 53?

[image]

Comment: Can you share real domain name and show your Route53 entries?

Comment: Answer has been updated with the records for this domain's hosted zone

Comment: If you want to host your zone in Route53, you should not change NS records within the zone. Now, you have to revert them back to original values, and then also update values at domain registry. If you cant recall what were the NS servers, just delete the zone and create new one, and after that update the domain registry NS servers (with the new set of name servers which will be assigned when you recreate your hosted zone)

Comment: I recreated the zone in Route 53 and copied the name server values over to the domain registry. Do you know what is to be done with the name server values i'm given in Lightsail? Should those be added to a new NS entry in the Route 53 zone?

Comment: You can use either LightsailDNS or Route53 to host your zone. If you are using Route53, then you don't have to do anything with Lightsail name server(s). If you would like to use Lightsail DNS, then you need to create your A record in Lightsail hosted zone, and add Lightsail name server to your domain registry.

Comment: Was able to get around this issue by removing the Lightsail DNS zone and using bncert to generate a new certificate, thank you for your help